# jupyter fails to open a directory to run a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter

The docker is running and I want to run a docker container in Windows 10. When I run the docker-compose from Windows power shell, some downloading jobs are completed, an error occurs, and the docker container cannot run. It seems that jupyter fails to build or open a directory. Anyone could help me about this problem? The command line and the error is as the following:

```
PS C:\Users\mmva> cd C:\Users\mmva\Documents\GitHub\CerebralCortex-DockerCompose
PS C:\Users\mmva\Documents\GitHub\CerebralCortex-DockerCompose> docker-compose up
Building jupyter
Step 1/19 : FROM jupyter/jupyterhub
latest: Pulling from jupyter/jupyterhub
efd26ecc9548: Extracting [==================================================>]  51.34MB/51.34MB
a3ed95caeb02: Download complete
298ffe4c3e52: Download complete
758b472747c8: Download complete
8b9809a68afc: Download complete
93b253b5483d: Download complete
ef8136abb53c: Download complete
ERROR: Service 'jupyter' failed to build: failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: Failed to OpenForBackup failed in Win32: open \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\eb9ac9d604f051d5490a876043809e7929197356387569bc50a3694b77d1b721\usr\share\man\man3\Locale::gettext.3pm.gz: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (0x1f) \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\eb9ac9d604f051d5490a876043809e7929197356387569bc50a3694b77d1b721\usr\share\man\man3\Locale::gettext.3pm.gz
```

**My docker version is 17.09.0-ce-win33 (13620).
I think the docker-compose's version is 3.
The content of docker-compose file:**

```
version: '3'

# IPTABLES RULES IF NECESSARY
#-A INPUT -i br+ -j ACCEPT
#-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
#-A OUTPUT -o br+ -j ACCEPT
#-A OUTPUT -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

# The .env file is for production use with server-specific configurations

services:
# Frontend web proxy for accessing services and providing TLS encryption
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: md2k-nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/site:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx-selfsigned.crt:/etc/ssh/certs/ssl-cert.crt
      - ./nginx/nginx-selfsigned.key:/etc/ssh/certs/ssl-cert.key
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - apiserver
      - grafana
      - jupyter

  apiserver:
    build: ../CerebralCortex-APIServer
    container_name: md2k-api-server
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
    links:
      - mysql
      - kafka
      - minio
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - MINIO_HOST=${MINIO_HOST:-minio}
      - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=${MINIO_ACCESS_KEY:-ZngmrLWgbSfZUvgocyeH}
      - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=${MINIO_SECRET_KEY:-IwUnI5w0f5Hf1v2qVwcr}
      - MYSQL_HOST=${MYSQL:-mysql}
      - MYSQL_DB_USER=${MYSQL_ROOT_USER:-root}
      - MYSQL_DB_PASS=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-random_root_password}
      - KAFKA_HOST=${KAFKA_HOST:-kafka}
      - JWT_SECRET_KEY=${MINIO_SECRET_KEY:-IwUnI5w0f5Hf1v2qVwcr}
      - FLASK_HOST=${FLASK_HOST:-0.0.0.0}
      - FLASK_PORT=${FLASK_PORT:-80}
      - FLASK_DEBUG=${FLASK_DEBUG:-False}
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data

# Data vizualizations
  grafana:
    image: "grafana/grafana"
    container_name: md2k-grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - influxdb
    environment:
      - GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=%(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/
      # - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=raintank-worldping-app,grafana-clock-panel,grafana-simple-json-datasource
    volumes:
      - timeseries-storage:/var/lib/grafana
      # - timeseries-storage:/etc/grafana

  influxdb:
    image: "influxdb:alpine"
    container_name: md2k-influxdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    volumes:
      - timeseries-storage:/var/lib/influxdb


# Data Science Dashboard Interface
  jupyter:
    build: ./jupyterhub
    container_name: md2k-jupyterhub
    ports:
      - 8000
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    pid: "host"
    environment:
      TINI_SUBREAPER: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./jupyterhub/conf:/srv/jupyterhub/conf
    command: jupyterhub --no-ssl --config /srv/jupyterhub/conf/jupyterhub_config.py



# Cerebral Cortex backend
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:0.10.2.0
    container_name: md2k-kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: ${MACHINE_IP:-10.0.0.1}
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 2000000
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "filequeue:4:1,processed_stream:16:1"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - data-storage:/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: md2k-zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    container_name: md2k-mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306 # Default mysql port
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-random_root_password}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE:-cerebralcortex}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER:-cerebralcortex}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-cerebralcortex_pass}
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - metadata-storage:/var/lib/mysql

  minio:
    image: "minio/minio"
    container_name: md2k-minio
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9000:9000 # Default minio port
    environment:
      - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=${MINIO_ACCESS_KEY:-ZngmrLWgbSfZUvgocyeH}
      - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=${MINIO_SECRET_KEY:-IwUnI5w0f5Hf1v2qVwcr}
    command: server /export
    volumes:
      - object-storage:/export

  cassandra:
    build: ./cassandra
    container_name: md2k-cassandra
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9160:9160 # Thrift client API
      - 9042:9042 # CQL native transport
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=cerebralcortex
    volumes:
      - data-storage:/var/lib/cassandra


volumes:
  object-storage:
  metadata-storage:
  data-storage:
  temp-storage:
  timeseries-storage:
  user-storage:
  log-storage
```

Comment: Paste this as text please.

Comment: I added the error text.

Comment: Post your docker, docker-compose versions. And, ideally, the docker-compose file (leaving out the private data). You can also add the whole console output (starting from invoking the command) - like here: https://github.com/docker/labs/issues/97

Comment: I added the information to my question

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Docker For Windows installed (I use Docker Toolbox) so it's hard for me to test this. There's one thing that I noticed though. You are using a [`jupyter/jupyterhub`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/jupyterhub/) image for 'jupyter' service. The Docker Hub page for this image states: 'JupyterHub images have moved to jupyterhub/jupyterhub as of 0.6 (April 2016)'. Try migrating your service to [`jupyterhub/jupyterhub`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/). Or first try if this cmd works: `docker run -it jupyterhub/jupyterhub echo 'Works!'`

Comment: so? any results?

Comment: No, the error still exists. I also try "docker run -it jupyterhub/jupyterhub echo 'works !'" and the result is an error stating "Unable to find image 'jupyterhub/jupyterhub:latest' locally"

Comment: Probably you need to pull it first: `docker pull jupyterhub/jupyterhub`